# passing parameters to a php from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I've done this before but for some reason the parameters are being passed oddly.

I have a javascript function that I've used to pass parameters, I've ran some tests and in the function the variables are correct.

These are just a few snippets of the js that relate to the issue:

```
var tdes = document.getElementById("taskDescription1").value;
var tnam = document.getElementById("taskName1").value;
var shif = document.getElementById("shift1").value;
var ttyp = document.getElementById("taskType1").value;
var date = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
var ooc = document.getElementById("ooc1").value;
var dateSplit = date.split('/');
var deadlineDate = "";



for( var i = 0; i < dateSplit.length; i++){
deadlineDate = deadlineDate + dateSplit[i]; 
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","subTask.php?q="+ encodeURIComponent(tdes) + "&w=" + encodeURIComponent(tnam) +"&e=" +encodeURIComponent(shif) + "&y=" + encodeURIComponent(ttyp) + "&b=" + encodeURIComponent(deadlineDate) + "&u=" + encodeURIComponent(ooc),true);
```

I ran a web console and this is what is actually getting passed...

```
http://***************/****/********/subTask.php?taskName1=test+taskname+works&taskDescription1=test+des&shift1=All&ooc1=Open&taskType1=normal&datepicker=06%2F28%2F2013
```

I'm not sure what's going on in between the xmlhttp.open and the GET method in php. None of these variables are getting passed.

Comment: The JavaScript looks all right I guess, and the URL should work. Try checking if you actually receive any GET parameters in your PHP, for example with `print_r($_GET)` at the top of your script.

Comment: Yeah that was the first thing I did, I didn't get anything when I tried to Print it out.

Comment: Just for the record, you *are* calling `xmlhttp.send()` after the `open()` call, right? That is, you're actually sending the request? (Perhaps add some more JS code?)

Comment: yes, I am calling the send after the open.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery - very straightforward format (I prefer POST...):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tdes = $("#taskDescription1").val();
    var tnam = $("#taskName1").val();
    var shif = $("#shift1").val();
    var ttyp = $("#taskType1").val();
    var date = $("#datepicker").val();
    var ooc = $("#ooc1").val();
    var dateSplit = date.split('/');
    var deadlineDate = "";

    for( var i = 0; i < dateSplit.length; i++){
        deadlineDate = deadlineDate + dateSplit[i]; 
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "subTask.php",
        data: "q="+ encodeURIComponent(tdes) + "&w=" + encodeURIComponent(tnam) +"&e=" +encodeURIComponent(shif) + "&y=" + encodeURIComponent(ttyp) + "&b=" + encodeURIComponent(deadlineDate) + "&u=" + encodeURIComponent(ooc),true),
        success: function(whatigot) {
            alert('Server-side response: ' + whatigot);
        } //END success fn
    }); //END $.ajax

}); //END document.ready()
```

Notice how easy the `success` callback function is to write... anything returned by subTask.php will be available within that function, as seen by the alert() example.

Just remember to include the jQuery library in the `<head>` tags:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Also, add this line to the top of your `subTask.php` file, to see what is happening:

```
<?php
    $q = $_POST["q"];
    $w = $_POST["w"];
    die("Value of Q is: " .$q. " and value of W is: " .$w);
```

The values of `q=` and `w=` will be returned to you in an alert box so that (at least) you can see what values they contained when received by subTask.php

Comment: The issue is that they're not being received by subtask, I was trying to avoid the JQuery to try to learn how to actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

Following script should help:

```
function ajaxObj( meth, url ) 
{   
var x = false;
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    x = new XMLHttpRequest();
else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
x.open( meth, url, true );
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;    
    }
}

    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "subTask.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
           console.log( ajax.responseText )
        }
    }
    ajax.send("u="+tdes+"&e="+tnam+ ...... pass all the other 'n' data );
```